# Isomorphy of $2$-dimensional $L$-modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras

> Let $L$ be the $2$-dimensional Lie algebra over $\mathbb C$ with basis $x, y$ and $[xy] = x$. Let $V$ be a vector space over $\mathbb C$ with basis $v_1, v_2$. Then $V$ is an $L$-module if we define multiplication by
>      $$xv_1 = 0,\quad xv_2 = v_1,\quad yv_1 = -v_1,\quad yv_2 = v_1$$
>   Show that $V$ is isomorphic to the adjoint module for $L$.

I have been trying to work with explicit $L$-module isomorphisms such as
   $$f:V\to L,\ \ \alpha v_1 + \beta v_2\mapsto \alpha x + \beta y$$

but when I try to validate the homomorphism condition $f(lv)=lf(v)$ for $l\in L,\ v\in V$ I always run into a dead end, e.g.
 $$f(y(\alpha v_1+\beta v_2))=(\beta-\alpha)x\ \ \ \ne\ \ -\alpha x=[y,f(\alpha v_1+\beta v_2)]$$

Any hints as to how I could show isomorphy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The eigenvectors for $y$ acting on $V$ are $v_1$ with eigenvalue $-1$ and $v_1+v_2$ with eigenvalue $0$. So these have to go (up to scalars) to $x$ (eigenvalue $-1$) and $y$ in the adjoint representation. Now you just have to check what (if any) scalar multiples work to match up the $x$ action.

That is, define a linear map $\phi: V \rightarrow L$ by $\phi(v_1)=ax$ and $\phi(v_1+v_2)=by$ for scalars $a$ and $b$. By design $\phi$ commutes with the action of $y$. Write out the equations $\phi(x v_1)=x \phi(v_1)$ and $\phi(x(v_1+v_2))=x \phi(v_1+v_2)$ to find a choice of $a,b$ that will work.

Comment: $[yy]=0$, okay, but $[yx]=-x$, so the eigenvalues are $0,-1$.

Comment: You are using right multiplication, no? That's how you wrote the action on $V$.

Comment: Are you referring to $v_1x=0$, etc.? I think I might have written them the wrong way round.

Comment: Yes, if you want it to be a left module, then you should put $x$ and $y$ on the left.

Comment: yes, sorry about that.

Comment: OK, I edited to take this change into account.

Comment: Could you quickly explain why your argument proves isomorphy? We have $yv_1=-v_1,y(v_1+v_2)=0$ and $[yx]=-x,[yy]=0$. So do equal eigenvalues imply isomorphy?

Comment: No, just the equality of the $y$ eigenvalues is not enough to prove isomorphy---one has to check compatibility with the action of $x$ as well. (Any choice of $a=b$ other than $0$ will work).

Comment: So basically we can define $f(av_1+b(v_1+v_2))=ax+by$ or $g(ax+by)=av_1+b(v_1+v_2)$, and these are $L$-module homomorphisms, because of the eigenvalue discussion above ?

Comment: As long as $a=b$, yes. Again, you should check what values give compatibility with the action of $x$. Just write out the two equations in the second paragraph of my answer explicitly.